# Laravel query sql

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Good night. I am trying to get back the latest and only 1 item from the database. But the problem is 3 items were entered in the database at the same time. So the date is the exact same down to the seconds. How do i get the latest by the created_at date and the ID that is >

See what i have below that was giving the problem:

```
$latest = $newInv->where('case_number', $request-> case_number)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->latest()->first();
```

What i was hoping to do but still fails how do i write this better maybe?

```
$latest = $newInv->where('case_number', $request->case_number)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->latest()->first();
```

Comment: Always the latest id must have the latest created_at date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add `latest()` and order by id in the query, 
following should work,

```
$latest = $newInv->where('case_number', $request->case_number)
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

**DOCS**

The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->latest()->first();
```

See more at [https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offsetv](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

**UPDATE**

If you have same value for the `created_at` then following should work,

**NOTE:** you need order by id in descending order to get the record with > ID

```
 $latest = $newInv->where('case_number', $request->case_number)
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
         ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
         ->first();
```

Comment: Still isn't working for me. I gave 5 records the same exact created_at time down to the seconds and its still that picking the latest one using ur method. :'(

Comment: @Slygoth then add order by id column just after created at